# Cannot update graphics driver for HP Envy 17 G6U46UA#ABA

Tags: laptop, drivers, intel-graphics, hp-envy

I have an HP Envy 17 G6U46UA#ABA and I am trying to run software that uses the graphics driver to display 3D graphics (Cinema 4D R23). I installed Windows 10 on it. When I start the program, I get this error message:

[image]

And then the application crashes. I have been trying to update the driver, but to no avail. I installed the HP Support Assistant tool, and it does not have any graphics drivers updates available. Similarly, when I try to update the graphics driver within Windows, it says there are no updates available.

The graphics are Intel HD Graphics 4600, but anything I download from Intel's website fails to install on the system.

What interesting is that the program works on Windows 8.1 which is also installed on another partition on the machine. But it doesn't work on the Windows 10 partition. What's interesting is that even though it is saying that version 20 is outdated, on the Windows 8 version where the software runs fine, it is using version 10. So I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that 26.20 is even appropriate for your hardware.  Intel doesn’t update the driver for Intel HD Graphics 4600 past whatever the most recent release for it.  When you say the driver fails to install can you provide specifics as an edit your question?

Comment: Go to this page and select OS, then expand all drivers section, download both drivers and install>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-m7-k000-notebook-pc-series/7182778/model/7146403?sku=G6U46UA